# Invoke webrequest -body containing variables

Tags: windows, variables, powershell

Morning people of stackoverflow,

I have an issue which google cant help me resolve.

We have a API which we authenticate with using the following code:

```
$DeviceNumber = Read-Host "Enter device number"
$URL= "https://URL.diskspace.website.com/v1/"
$pass = 'password123'
$postParam = '{"password":"$pass"}'
$AuthToken = ""


#Log in to the URL
$IWRLogin = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $URL/login/$env:username -ContentType application/json -Body $postParam
```

This returns a Authentication code which is then parsed when using the API.

However, the above does not work. For this to work I need to have my password hard coded, like the following:

```
$postParam = '{"password":"password123"}'
```

Ideally I want to have the user enter their password, it be stored and be used in the body of the invoke webrequest. Infact I would like to use the get-credentials feature of powershell because this will encrypt the password which is always good.

Please help me out guys :)

PS. Variables are random to hide sensitive information, if it doesn't make sense that is why..

Comment: By using single quotes in your $postParam = '{"password":"$pass"}', you prevent variable expansion. Replace single quotes with double quotes and escape double quotes in your json body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$pass = 'password123'
$postParam = @{ "password" = "$pass" }
$json = ConvertTo-Json $postParam
```

And use the $json variable in your Invoke-WebRequest call.

Comment: You are are freaking amazing. With this I should be able to use the Get-credentials. Thanks David!